# OpenCV CMake undefined reference to function

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, cmake, clion

I have problem with simple OpenCV app build with CMake. 
I have spent many hours to get to know what is wrong but still I have totally no idea...

I am using CLion as IDE on Ubuntu 18.04

My **CMakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(qt_segmentation)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable(qt_segmentation main.cpp)

target_include_directories(qt_segmentation PUBLIC ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(qt_segmentation ${OPENCV_LIBS})
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<cv::getVersionRevision()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler itself seems to work properly I can compile my file with following command with success:

`` g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -o main ``

Error:

```
====================[ Build | qt_segmentation | Debug ]=========================
/home/bienqq/clion-2019.3.4/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/bienqq/CLionProjects/qt-segmentation/cmake-build-debug --target qt_segmentation -- -j 2
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/bienqq/CLionProjects/qt-segmentation/cmake-build-debug
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable qt_segmentation
CMakeFiles/qt_segmentation.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/bienqq/CLionProjects/qt-segmentation/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `cv::getVersionRevision()'
CMakeFiles/qt_segmentation.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:648: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles/qt_segmentation.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::operator=(cv::String const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:656: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/qt_segmentation.dir/build.make:83: recipe for target 'qt_segmentation' failed
make[3]: *** [qt_segmentation] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:75: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/qt_segmentation.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/qt_segmentation.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/qt_segmentation.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/qt_segmentation.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:118: recipe for target 'qt_segmentation' failed
make: *** [qt_segmentation] Error 2
```

I have also printed values of CMake properties:

```
OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/local/include;/usr/local/include/opencv

OpenCV_LIBS=opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab
```

From my point of view I have checked everything but still it does not work ...

Could You please help?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of investigation it seems that CMake is **case sensitive**:
When changing:

```
target_link_libraries(qt_segmentation ${OPENCV_LIBS})
```

to

```
target_link_libraries(qt_segmentation ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

As property in CMake suggest:

```
OpenCV_LIBS=opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;opencv_dnn;opencv_features2d;opencv_flann;opencv_highgui;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_imgproc;opencv_ml;opencv_objdetect;opencv_photo;opencv_shape;opencv_stitching;opencv_superres;opencv_video;opencv_videoio;opencv_videostab
```

Everythink works well